# Spring-bootで関連付けされているテーブルのデータを一括で取得する方法

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Spring-bootというか、Hibernateの質問になるのでしょうか。
以下の様なテーブル構成のDBから社員情報を取得したい場合に、社員Classはどのようなアノテーションをつければ良いでしょうか。
OneToManyを使用すればできそうかと思ったのですが、関連付けする項目が社員テーブルにはないですし、関連付けテーブルではOneToOneにしかなりません。

質問自体がわかりにくい、このような方法では取得できない、そもそもこのような構成がおかしいという等々、細かい点でもご指摘いただけると助かります。

社員テーブル

ID,NAME
1, TAROU
2, HANAKO

部署テーブル
ID,NAME 
1, 部署A
2, 部署B
3, 部署C

社員と部署関連付けテーブル（TAROUは部署Aと部署Bに属している。）
ID,社員ID,部署ID
1,1,1
2,1,2
3,2,2

結果として以下の様なClassで取得したいです。

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shain")
class 社員 {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @Column
  String name;

  // ここに何らかのアノテーション等の設定で取得可能かと思っています。
  List<部署> 所属部署;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この場合、多対多の関連なので@ManyToManyを使います。

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shain")
class 社員 {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @Column
  String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name = "社員と部署関連付けテーブルのテーブル名",
    joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "社員ID（関連付けテーブルのカラム名）", referencedColumnName = "id（社員テーブルのIDカラム名）")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "部署ID（関連付けテーブルのカラム名）", referencedColumnName = "id（部署テーブルのIDカラム名）")
    }
  )
  private List<部署> 所属部署;
}
```